# Connecting to Rails Service using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a task to display some data on the page that is done in RoR. We are using masonry for user experience. There will be some sliders on the page, where user will move them left or right. Based on his selection, the data will be shown.

We were thinking to make a rails service which will pull the data from the DB in time intervals (not on user request). And when the user requests data, it will return it (not querying the db all the time).
I am here at loss. I have done simliar things with AJAX/Service (.NET). Where I made a service (method) to get me data. I used AJAX to get data back form the method and it worked fine.

The data in the DB will have to be HTML formatted (not formatted in the DB). We have still not decided what will format the data, RoR Service or Client JS???

What is the skeleton connector in JS to connect to Rails Service?
Will I be able to receive my data as Arrays? Strings are also fine.

Comment: *We have still not decided what will format the data, RoR Service or Client JS???* — there are pros and cons to both approaches.

Comment: *is the skeleton connector in JS to connect to Rails Service?* — The same as to connect to any other HTTP service. Look for an [introductory Ajax guide](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html).

Comment: *Will I be able to receive my data as Arrays?* — Not as such. You could serialise a data structure into a data format, send it over HTTP and then de-serialise it at the other end. JSON is the usual format used for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple json to retrieve any data you want via ajax, and then parse and render it on your page

In your controller you can specify type of your respond. E.g.

```
respond_to do |format|
format.json {'status' => 'ok', params{'param1':'value1'....}}
end
```

ANd then with jquery&ajax or whatever you are using, you can send get request to this controller and it will return json with params. After you can parse it with js and render on your page

Comment: Is there simple example how to do it, and I will pick it up from there? :)